# Do we use material conditional in regular mathematics?

Tags: logic, quantifiers

I have been confused by the definition and truth table of material conditional (MC) for quite a while and the only responses I have received are variations of 'it is correct' and 'I should just get used to it'.

Today I discovered an interesting MC example, which regular mathematicians would never agree to as true, yet according to MC rules it is for most of natural numbers:

$x$ is prime $\implies$ $x + 2$ is prime

According to the definition of MC, this statement is true for all even numbers (except 2), all non-prime odd numbers, as well as for a small fraction of prime numbers (every first prime in a twin-prime pair). Only for the prime numbers that are not the first prime in a twin prime pair, does it fail to hold. This statement is true for about 99% of natural numbers.

Yet it is clear and understood according to regular mathematics that this is statement is simply wrong. By regular mathematics I mean 99% of mathematics, when we're not studying foundational issues, logic, and so on.

My question is, is it correct to state that MC has practically no relevance to regular mathematics? If yes, is it a good idea to insist on 'getting used to the MC definition', 'just treat MC as a truth table', or 'try not to worry too much about MC' when studying logic?

**Edit 1**: I would like to expand on what I said, in response to the comments mentioning quantified (or first-order) implication. Let's denote it by $_{\implies}^{\forall}$. The following is false in logic as well as regular mathematics:

$x$ is prime $_{\implies}^{\forall}$ $x+2$ is prime

However, there's agreement here only because we have counterexamples (e.g., $x=7$ and many more). We could reach the same conclusion even if we discarded the true parts of the MC truth table, i.e., the three clauses F$\implies$F, F$\implies$T, and T$\implies$T. We could replace their true values with something like, "N/A", "Unknown", or "Inconclusive", and our first-order logic, and the rest of regular mathematics would still work just fine. (Of course in that case, the MC table would no longer be a complete truth-table).

Quantified-implication <s>does not need the MC truth-table, or even for MC to exist. All it</s> requires <s>is</s> the result of a counterexample search (i.e., a case of $A \land \lnot B$, where, e.g., $A$ is '$x$ is prime' and $B$ is '$x+2$ is prime'). If the counterexample search is complete, and a counterexample is found, $_{\implies}^{\forall}$ is false. If the search is complete and no counterexample found, $_{\implies}^{\forall}$ is true. (If a counterexample is not found, and the search is not complete, or we're not sure if the search is complete, the true values of MC only mislead, never help).

In other words, we introduce true clauses in MC, because (maybe) we like a completed truth-table, at the expense of confusing students, when those true values are useless, and infact harmful, once we start using quantified implication with counterexample search.

**Edit 2**: I should clarify (and maybe correct) myself. Quantified-implication does need the MC truth table. So I stand corrected. However, MC truth table does not make much sense without the use of a quantifier. So what I'm trying to say is the following:

- Take the MC formula $\lnot [A \land \lnot B]$ and ignore the MC symbol $\implies$.
- The formula $\lnot [A \land \lnot B]$ is combined with $\forall$ to form quantified-implication $_{\implies}^{\forall}$ as follows:

$A(x) {}_{\implies}^{\forall} B(x)$ defined as $\forall x (\lnot [A(x) \land \lnot B(x)])$

- What that means is that the MC formula finds its use *through first-order quantifiers* in mathematics. However, in my opinion, if we try to ascribe 'implication' or 'if ... then' or any other meaning to the MC formula itself, instead of treating it as a mere formula, that causes needless confusion.

**Edit 3**: After the answer by Alex Kruckman, I should add that that's another helpful test-case, i.e., prove implication mathematically before invoking MC. However, it means the MC truth-table was only consulted after-the-fact. The implication was established mathematically, not through propositional logic. So the two use-cases so far: (1) as part of a quantifier, (2) as a pre-proved implication. My prime example doesn't fall in either, and hence I'm still of the opinion that there are problematic consequences of MC (and I'm not even talking about the paradoxes).

Comment: Why do you believe no "regular" mathematician would agree that your example is true for some choices of $x$? The implication in mathematical proofs (as opposed to discussions of proofs, perhaps) is always the material conditional. This is often somewhat concealed by the vernacular. In a proof involving your example, you might write something like "if $x$ is not prime, there is nothing to prove.".

Comment: Let me ask you a simple english language yes-or-no question: Does $x$ being a prime imply that $x+2$ is also going to be a prime?

Comment: If $P(x)$ means $x$ is prime, then $\forall x (P(x) \implies P(x + 2))$ is false. We read your English language question as if the $x$ is universally quantified. That doesn't mean the statement $P(x) \implies P(x + 2)$ is not true for some values of $x$. It is the quantification that is the issue here, not the meaning of implication.

Comment: So you agree with me. We never use MC in regular mathematics? We only use first-order, quantified, implication (aided by counterexample search) in regular mathematics (which has nothing to do with MC).

Comment: I certainly do not agree with that statement. Many mathematical statements have a very complex quantifier structure. When expressing such statements in natural language, we have to be more explicit about the quantifier structure.

Comment: We do generally use material implication, but it is mostly in the context of predicate logic with quantifiers involved, not propositional logic alone.

Comment: "Only for the prime numbers that are not the first prime in a twin prime pair, does it fail to hold. This statement is true for about 99% of natural numbers. Yet it is clear and understood according to regular mathematics that this is statement is simply wrong." There's no tension between these two facts: a formula holding on almost all elements doesn't mean that the universal closure of that formula is true, and there's an implicit universal closure when we say "If $x$ is prime then $x+2$ is prime" without further elaboration.

Comment: "We only use first-order, quantified, implication (aided by counterexample search) in regular mathematics (which has nothing to do with MC)" Huh? Quantified implication is *built on* the material conditional; it's absolutely related to it. In fact, that's what the real argument for the material conditional is: that in order for universal quantification and for expressions like "$\forall x(P(x)\rightarrow Q(x))$" to each mean what they should, we need to interpret each instance of the inner implication via the material conditional. Tl;dr: **no, I don't agree with you at all**.

Comment: @Ian - If it were not for quantified implication (let's denote it with $\forall \implies$), F$\implies$F, F$\implies$T, and T$\implies$T, all being true, by themselves would turn regular mathematics into the most illogical thing that exists in the world. I'd love to be proven wrong. I doubt it.

Comment: $T \Rightarrow T$ being true is as essential to the concept as $T \Rightarrow F$ being false is. What is subtle is why $F \Rightarrow F$ and $F \Rightarrow T$ are understood as true, and that is because we want the truth value of $\forall x \, P(x) \Rightarrow Q(x)$ to be independent of the properties of the $x$ in the domain such that $\neg P(x)$.

Comment: An important point the comments have missed is that in a formal proof, we want everything we say to be true (or at least as true as the premises). This means if we have an implication somewhere in our proof, and the antecedent is false, then we want the whole implication to be true, so that when it is conjoined with the other lines in the formal proof, the entirety is still as true as the premises.

Comment: You don't understand first-order logic. If you did, you would understand that first-order logic is not just about taking the universal closure of quantifier-free formulas. If you wish to attack mathematical practice or mathematical foundations, then you must first become fluent in the subject you wish to attack ([Brouwer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L._E._J._Brouwer) should be your exemplar.)

Comment: "I think it is safe to say that we're telling the younger mathematicians, in a highly misleading way, that (MC-based) logic and set theory is how you do higher mathematics!" Well, MC-based logic and set theory *is* how you do higher mathematics, so this is not misleading at all.

Comment: Regarding Edit 3: "Established mathematically, not through propositional logic" is a contradiction. To establish something mathematically means to provide a proof, and propositional logic (including MC) is baked into what we mean by "proof" at a deep level. Mathematicians have developed a precise and efficient language for communicating mathematics. When we talk about implication or say "if then", we always mean MC. If this disturbs you greatly, you're welcome to use language differently in private. But you'll have a very hard time communicating with others about mathematics.

Comment: As was mentioned elsewhere, the propositional logic situation for material implication is when you don't know whether $P$ is true or whether $Q$ is true, all you know is that if actually $P$ is true then $Q$ must also be true. For this to be interesting, $P$ has to be something hard to prove or disprove and yet powerful enough that it can imply something which is nontrivially related to $P$. This can come up with statements like the Riemann hypothesis or "ZF set theory is consistent".

Answer (score 7):

In the comments to Dan Christensen's answer, you ask for examples in "regular mathematics" where the material conditional finds use without a quantifier in a meaningful way.

Of course this happens - mathematicians prove conditional theorems all the time. Many important theorems in number theory are conditional on difficult open problems. For example, you might prove a theorem like "If the Riemann Hypothesis holds, then we get some bound on the error term in the prime number theorem." See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_hypothesis#Distribution_of_prime_numbers). Let's abbreviate this example theorem by RH$\rightarrow$EB.

You can see the truth table for the material conditional at work here:

- If someone comes along and proves RH, then because the theorem RH$\rightarrow$EB is true, the error bound EB must be true.
- On the other hand, if RH turns out to be false, then the error bound EB might still be true or it might not. In this situation (when RH is false, and regardless of whether EB is true or not), we do not have to turn around and start looking for a mistake in the proof of our theorem RH$\rightarrow$EB. The theorem RH$\rightarrow$EB is suddenly much less interesting, but it is still true!

Comment: By 'meaningful use of material conditional' I mean using the MC truth-table to reach the conclusion. For RH $\implies$ EB, we don't know the value of RH, so we didn't really make use of the truth-table, because one of the inputs is unknown. Only *after* we used mathematics (and not propositional logic) to *prove* that were RH true, it would lead to EB being true, can we go back and consult the MC truth-table to think about the consequences once the truth-value of RH is known.

Comment: @user101043 You won't find anyone writing down an unquantified conditional statement $P\rightarrow Q$ and "using the MC truth table to reach the conclusion", just because this is an entirely trivial thing to do. If I already know the truth values of $P$ and $Q$, and I'm  a mathematician, then the truth or falsity of $P\rightarrow Q$ is obvious to me *because I have internalized the MC truth table*. It's much better just to specify the truth values of $P$ and $Q$!

Comment: But I don't really understand your apparent rejection of my example. Imagine that tomorrow someone finds a counterexample to RH. And the next day someone verifies the error bound EB with a proof that's independent RH. Do you deny that the theorem RH$\rightarrow$EB is still true? Now ask the same questions for the other three rows of the MC truth table. If your answers agree with the truth table, it seems you buy the MC. If not, tell me which one you diagree with.

Comment: And that is part of the point of this question. In the case of $x$ is prime $\implies$ $x+2$ is prime, we know this is not true, and yet we accept it to be true for 99% of natural numbers, including for cases where neither $x$ nor $x+2$ is prime, because the MC truth-table says so (that when both the inputs are false, the "implication" holds).

Comment: @user101043 As has already been pointed out to you, your supposed example is nonsense. There is no contradiction at all between a statement being true for 99% of numbers but not true for *all* numbers. And it has nothing to do with MC.  $x\neq 42$ is true for much more than 99% of all numbers, but $\forall x\, (x\neq 42)$ is false.

Comment: I'm not rejecting your example. In fact, it's a helpful use-case, and thank you for that. I have added an edit to my question (edit 3).

Answer (score 0):

> I have been confused by the definition and truth table of material
> conditional (MC) for quite a while and the only responses I have
> received are variations of 'it is correct' and 'I should just get used
> to it'.

The definition of the material conditional usually given as $A\to B \equiv \neg [A \land \neg B]$ as well as each line of its truth table can be formally derived from first principles using a simple form of natural deduction.

- $A\to B \equiv \neg [A \land \neg B]~~~$ [Formal Proof](http://www.dcproof.com/DeriveImplies.html) (19 lines)
- $A \land B \to [A\to B]~~~~~~~$  Line 1 of the truth table [Formal Proof](http://www.dcproof.com/ImpliesLine1.html) (6 lines)
- $A \land \neg B \to \neg [A \to B]~$ Line 2 of the truth table
  [Formal Proof](http://www.dcproof.com/ImpliesLine2.html) (8 lines)
- $\neg B \to [A\to B]~~~~~~~~~~~$ Lines 3 and 4 of the truth table
  [Formal Proof](http://www.dcproof.com/ImpliesLines3-4.html) (8 lines)

> My question is, is it correct to state that MC has practically no
> relevance to regular mathematics?

No. Quite the contrary. MC is unavoidable in "regular" mathematics. You seem to be quite misinformed on this matter. If you want to make a name for yourself, find the error in any of the above proofs. The first is probably the most important. (Only 19 lines!)

Comment: Can you provide me a single example in regular mathematics (outside of logic, up to first semester graduate level), where the formula $\lnot [A \land \lnot B]$ finds use without a quantifier in a meaningful way?

Comment: @user101043 There are almost no mathematical proofs without any implicit quantifiers.